# Linear system without base points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, algebraic-curves

Let $D$ be a divisor and $V$ a vectorial subspace of $L(D)$. The set of the divisors $S=\{(f)+D\mid f\in V\}$ is called a linear system. A point $P\in C$ is a base point if for every divisor $D\in S$, we have $P\in D$.

I'm looking for easy examples of linear systems without base points. This will help me to see this abstract definition in a more concrete way.

Thanks

Comment: The classic example is $X=\mathbf P^n$ and $D=H$, a hyperplane. Then the _complete_ linear system $L(H)$ is the set of _all_ hyperplanes in $\mathbf P^n$. (Exercise: if $H'$ is another hyperplane, find a rational function $f$ such that $H'=(f)+H$.) I hope you can see why this has no base points!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh my doubt is my basic. How a hyperplane could be a divisor? For example, if we take the hyperplane $H:X_1+X_2=1$ in $\mathbb A^2$, Is $H$ a divisor?

Comment: Yes. A divisor just means a subvariety of codimension 1 (or more generally, a formal sum of those things, with integer coefficients).

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I'm sorry, I'm a really beginner in this subject. I'm trying to understand this using only this definition of a divisor: a divisor is a sum $n_1P_1+\ldots+n_kP_k$ where the $P_i$'s are points and the $n_i$'s are integers.

Comment: Dear user: **no**, that is not the correct definition of divisor **unless** your variety $X$ is a curve. Are you reading a book about curves? I suggest that you look in e.g. Shafarevich's book to get a better idea of the more general theory.

Comment: On the other hand, for the purposes of your original question, we might as well let $n=1$, so we are talking about the curve $X=\mathbf P^1$, and let $H$ be a point $p \in \mathbf P^1$. (Note that a hyperplane in $\mathbf P^1$ is indeed a point!)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I'm studying Fulton's algebraic curves book, that's why I'm only interested in this moment is when $X$ is a curve.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. See my last comment. Good luck!